# Extension of Excel files remains when doing an import loop in Stata

Tags: excel, loops, import, stata

I don't understand why when running the following simple piece of code my files get saved as `xxx.xls.dta` instead of `xxx.dta` and how to fix that.

```
clear all
cd "C:\Users\User\Documents\PhD\Research\Data\acqua_costiera"
global RawAcqua "C:\Users\User\Documents\PhD\Research\Data\acqua_costiera"

local acquacost : dir "C:\Users\User\Documents\PhD\Research\Data\acqua_costiera" files "*.xls", respectcase

foreach f of local acquacost {
    import excel using "$RawAcqua\\`f'", cellrange(B4:N43310) firstrow clear
    save "`f'.dta", replace
}
```

I have tried looking at other similar pieces of code online but I don't really get what is my mistake.

I'm looping over all of the files in that directory, but the files are named "acqua_costiera_`year'" so I guess some other loop might work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be easily illustrated using the following toy example:

```
local acquacost one.xls two.xls three.xls

foreach f of local acquacost {
    display "`f'.dta"
}

one.xls.dta
two.xls.dta
three.xls.dta
```

You need to tell Stata to only keep the filename, not the extension:

```
foreach f of local acquacost {
    display "`= substr("`f'", 1, strpos("`f'", ".") - 1)'.dta"
}
```

Here i use the `strpos()` function to get the position of the first period and then use this as a reference point to extract the relevant portion of the `string` using the `substr()` function.

For saving the file with the proper name just use `save`, instead of `display`.

Comment: This is exactly what I could not do but was aiming at doing. Thank you so much.